# Mapping Foreign Key as Primary Key Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, composite-id

I have the following table scenario:

```
User
    - Id       (PK)
    - Username 

Advert
    - Id    (PK)
    - Title

AdvertPhoto
    - Advert (PK) (Also a FK for Advert table)
    - Image

Bid
    - Advert (PK) (Also a FK for Advert table)
    - User   (PK) (Also a FK for User table)
    - Value
```

Ok, I'm trying to map these entities with the code below:

```
public class AdvertMapping : BaseMapping<Advert> {
    public AdvertMapping() : base("Advert") {
        Id(model => model.Id).Not.Nullable().Unique().GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(model => model.Title).Not.Nullable().Length(100).Insert().Update();
    }
}

public class AdvertPhotoMapping : BaseMapping<Advert> {
    public AdvertPhotoMapping() : base("AdvertPhoto") {
        Id(model => model.Advert)
            .Column("Id")
            .GeneratedBy.Foreign("Advert");

        Map(model => model.Description).Nullable();
        Map(model => model.Photo).CustomSqlType("image").Not.Nullable();
        References(model => model.Advert, "Advert").Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class BidMapping { //: BaseMapping<Bid> {
    public BidMapping() : base("Bid") {
        Id(model => model.Advert, "Advert").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Advert");
            CompositeId()
                .KeyReference(model => model.Advert, "Advert")
                .KeyReference(model => model.User, "User");

            Map(model => model.Value).Not.Nullable().Insert().Update();
            References(model => model.Advert, "Advert").Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Ok, I'm getting an exception when the Fluent NHibernate is trying to reference the Advert column in the `AdvertPhotoMapping` class and I don't know if the `BidMapping` CompositeId is mapped properly.

The exception I got is:

`{"Could not determine type for: SYB.Engine.Entities.Advert, SYB.Engine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Advert)"}`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is how I would map one to one relationships:

```
public class AdvertPhotoMapping : BaseMapping<Advert> {
    public AdvertPhotoMapping() : base("AdvertPhoto") {
        Id(model => model.Advert)
            .Column("Id")
            .GeneratedBy.Foreign("Advert");

        Map(model => model.Description).Nullable();
        Map(model => model.Photo).CustomSqlType("image").Not.Nullable();
        HasOne(model => model.Advert).Constrained();
    }
}

public class AdvertMapping : BaseMapping<Advert> {
    public AdvertMapping() : base("Advert") {
        Id(model => model.Id).Not.Nullable().Unique().GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(model => model.Title).Not.Nullable().Length(100).Insert().Update();
        HasOne(x => x.AdvertPhoto).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Also you shouldn't need the References mapping in `BidMapping`.  It should look like this:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyReference(model => model.Advert, "Advert")
    .KeyReference(model => model.User, "User");

     Map(model => model.Value).Not.Nullable().Insert().Update();
```